# nghide class is override but after set display block is not working in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have show the spinner during upload the image and showthat time if response is not received from firebse.i am using $("#showLoaded").css({ 'display': "block" }); its not woring propery but loader is not display proerly and i have also used !important with this buts its not applied.i have override the class="nghide" i don't understand what's the wrong in my code?

```js
$scope.uploadBackgroundImage = function(event) {
  $("#showLoaded").css({ 'display': "block" });

  //Get the value from the input field and assign into the fire-base node
  var userProductImg       = $("#imgId")[0].files[0];
  var PRODUCT_STORAGE_REF  = firebase.storage().ref('user/image');

  //get the date as well as put the imageURL from node
  var rn = new Date().getTime().toString();
  var task = PRODUCT_STORAGE_REF.child(rn).put(userProductImg).then(function(snapshot) {
    $timeout(function(){
      $scope.backgroundImageURL.push(snapshot.downloadURL);
      $("#showLoaded").css({ 'display': "none" });
      localStorage.setItem('userImageURL', $scope.backgroundImageURL);
    }, 0);
  })
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center;" id="showLoaded">
    <img class="imageLoaderGif" src="images/googleLoader.gif">
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: `$("#showLoaded").css({ 'display': "block !important" });` should work

Comment: No sir its not work  and in the  <div="ng-show" class="ng-hide"> ng-hide class is add how to remove this class from the div ?

Comment: Why would you use `display` CSS property? `ngShow` `ngHide` directives already do that

Comment: Sir for show the loader but after remove the display spinner is not show again due to class="ng-hide" is added on a div  tell me sir how to remove this class?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want. Maybe this working demo with ngShow will help you to understand how it works :) https://plnkr.co/edit/rbFDgTBP3Fz95IdmekzL?p=preview

Comment: sir I want to remove only class="ngHide" from the div that will be added dynamic  how to remvoe this ?

Comment: But why using  **class** for showing/hiding element? AngularJS provides you existing directives `ngShow` `ngHide` that does the same! Please read some documentation about that and check example I provided to you

Comment: sir i will check and i am not using class for showing this but after $scope.imageLoader = true;  class will be added in div i have not added this please check the image in which class is added ?

Comment: by using `ng-show`, `ng-hide` comes from `AngularJS`. So create an expression inside your `html` using `ng-show`. Or just set it to true by default. `ng-show="true"`. You are messing up angularjs by using jquery .. Dont do that!

Comment: In this case you should use ng-class instead ng-show/hide which class will store a CSS property "display: block !important".

Comment: @red, ok sir but if we have to set the condition bydefault true spinner  is show without select any image , i have to show only spinner if backgroundImageURL.length > 0 ?

Comment: You could try that.

Comment: ok sir i will try

Comment: @hanif, Now its working for me show after remvoe the ng-show from html and set only block property.after set this, spinner is loaded byfault we have set display:none, to the function after this model is open.  but sir why ng-hide is applied after use ng-show ?